# Android java.lang.VerifyError only on 1.5

Tags: android

I have the following code which gets call in my main activity's onCreate method

```
 public static ErrorReporter getInstance(){
  if (instance == null){
   instance = new ErrorReporter();
  }
  return instance;
 }
```

Only on android 1.5 calling the above method causes java.lang.VerifyError. I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Any hints on how to solve this problem

Comment: What's `ErrorReporter`? This kind of exceptions occur when you are trying to use something which is not in the SDK. Maybe, inside the `ErrorReporter` class there are some libraries that are available for Android >= 1.6.

Comment: ErrorReporter is a class that I defined which implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler, which helps me to find out what caused a force close in my app. The above function is used to get the instance of the class. As soon as I call this method in onCreate() of my main activity I get a error (java.lang.VerifyError) and this happens only in 1.5

Comment: I've stated seeing this same problem with Android 1.5.  I have a primitive defined as a public static field in a class.  When I try to access the static field from another class in 1.5 I get a java.lang.VerifyError.

Comment: I was using some function which was not available in 1.5. Used reflection to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a function in ErrorReporter class which was not available in 1.5. Used reflection to take care of the unavailable function and the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Simply do a build on 1.5 and you'll see where is the culprit...

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem when i try to set the listadatper for a listview :)

check this

```
private void setResultListListAdapter() {
    mListAdapter_ = new ListAdapter(mContext_,
            R.layout.dsg_detailed_list_row, mLstStops_);
    setListAdapter(mListAdapter_);
}
```

gets a VerifyError before mListAdapter_ gets initialized.. so something with this...

**new ListAdapter(mContext_,
                R.layout.dsg_detailed_list_row, mLstStops_);**

but there's nothing which is just available in 1.5 :=//
strange thing...

also in 2 other classes this code works just fine... :=)

hope someone knowes more, thanks a lot!
(everything initialized, everything checked...setListAdapter never gets called)

---

**SOLUTION (for me)**

***it really was a method which wasn't supported in Android 1.5***

mConvertView_.setTag(uniqueIntID, ViewHolder);

ViewHolder is a static class, instead of using normal View.gettag(),
because of different layouts i was using the above method.. so :=)

the second is supported, View.getTag()